# Using string in void in another void?

Tags: c#

I am trying to navigate page, using different useragents. I have a random string generator, a timer that changes it every second (generate new random string every second), and a navigate. My question is, how to use string useragent (which is being changed every second) in another void ?

```
public static string RandomString(Random r)
{
     string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     int cnt = r.Next(5, 33);
     for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
     {
         int idx = r.Next(0, s.Length);
         sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1));
     }
     return sb.ToString();
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var r = new Random();
     string useragent = RandomString(r);      
     timer2.Stop();
     timer2.Interval = 1;
     timer2.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     Navigate("http://example.org",useragent,null);    
}
```

Comment: Because timer1_Tick has also timer in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useragent` in global scope

```
private string useragent = string.Empty;
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = new Random();
    useragent = RandomString(r);
    timer2.Stop();
    timer2.Interval = 1;
    timer2.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(useragent)) 
        return;
    Navigate("http://example.org", useragent, null);
}
```

EDIT:

You should generate the string only when it is needed while navigating, so use this

```
private Random r = new Random();
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Navigate("http://example.org", RandomString(r), null);
}
```

Comment: When I use it, useragent is always empty.

Comment: So your `timer_Tick2` is not running.

Comment: @user198989 Where are you startig `timer2`?

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Interval = 1;
            timer2.Start();
}

Comment: It only uses 1 same random useragent string

Comment: If every `Navigate` uses random string, then you should try my edit